# Reingold Tilford layout with a Python NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, graph-theory

I have a 4500 nodes directed acyclic graph (a tree) describing the structure of a company where each node is an employee and the directed edges represent a "manages" relationship.

I have implemented this graph in Pyton 3.9 with networkX 2.5.

After some attempts exporting networkX to GraphML and trying to visually render it with Gephi I gave up and found that the igraph library (with its Python wrapper) does have a very interesting Reingold Tilford (RT) but I do not like the final graphical result.

Is there a way to impose the RT layout on a networkX graph?

Thanks

Comment: Any progress on this or did you give up and use igraph?

Comment: Hi Ben I gave up and could not find a suitable way of using the RT layout. Take care.